# Loop carousel slider in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, wp-query, theme-development

Hello i create a custom post type clients to add client image but i was not able to loop all here my code

I want this code to loop

```
     <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x col-xs-6" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>

i tried like this 

<?php


$argss=array('post_type'=>'clients','post_status'=>'published');
                $query1 = new WP_Query($argss);


         if ( $query1->have_posts() ) : while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post(); 

         ?>
         <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail(array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>




                            </div>

         </div>
           <?php  endwhile; endif;?>
```

Comment: I would confirm you are getting any posts returned from your query. You need to change post_status to **publish**. Currently you have **published**

Comment: Yes i am getting but proper slider i was not able to get